# ContextFactory cannot be found in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse based application which is being ported from Java 8 to Java 11. Since `javax.xml` and friends was removed from the JDK, I had to add it as an Import-Package to every plug-in that needed them.

Now however, when run this code

```java
Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class).createMarshaller();
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.ContextFinder.loadClass(ContextFinder.java:135)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.safeLoadClass(ContextFinder.java:480)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:184)
```

I can add `com.sun.xml.bind`, which should have the dependency, but nothing happens. This is understandable, since OSGi rules prevents hacking into another plug-in via reflection.

However I cannot add Require-Bundle nor Import-Package to the JDK or the bundle around `javax.xml.bind`.

[There is a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=541264) surrounding this issue, but I cannot find  a good solution for my application in the comments. Still I assume it can be fixed for an Eclipse application, else Eclipse itself shouldn't be able to run on Java 11.

How do I fix this exception?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can add com.sun.xml.bind"? Also importing the package?

Comment: @nitind Yes, and using a bundle providing the package, like [jaxb-impl](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.2)

Comment: Import-package needs a proper bundle that exports the package, like the one built by the Orbit project.

Comment: @nitind Yes. So?

Comment: My bad. Didn't realize the manifest had been added in that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found an OSGi compatible way to fix this exception:

1. add the following implementations to the target platform

   - `org.apache.servicemix.specs.jaxb-api-2.2` (from Maven central)
   - `com.sun.xml.bind` (from the Eclipse platform; this is the one that contains the `ContextFactory`)
2. make sure these bundles are started with your application
3. make sure the Apache bundle is started before everything else

So in Tycho, this would look like this:

```xml
                <bundleStartLevel>
                    <bundle>
                        <id>org.apache.servicemix.specs.jaxb-api-2.2</id>
                        <autoStart>true</autoStart>
                        <level>1</level>
                    </bundle>
                </bundleStartLevel>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <artifactId>org.eclipse.e4.rcp</artifactId>
                        <type>eclipse-feature</type>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <type>p2-installable-unit</type>
                        <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.specs.jaxb-api-2.2</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <type>p2-installable-unit</type>
                        <artifactId>com.sun.xml.bind</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm too using jaxb in my application ([JMSToolBox](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox)) and too migrated from Java 1.8 to Java 11 and didn't had this problem
In my plugin, I have a "lib" directory with the`"jaxb-ri"`jar and its dependencies (from maven):

- jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar
- jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar
- javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar
- istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar

Then the plugin references those jars (MANIFEST.MF + build.properties) and I don't have any problem

The plugin [is here](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox/tree/dev/org.titou10.jtb.core)

Comment: ...that is against anything OSGi stands for, isn't it?